# Complicated CSS n-th child selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to achieve a complicated type of n-th child selection with CSS and I'm not sure whether it's possible. If it is, might anyone know how to achieve it. (I found [this guide](http://nthmaster.com/) but it doesn't seem to have a solution near what I need)

The desired result is a sequence that looks like this:

R B Y Y Y B R Y Y Y R B Y Y Y B R Y Y Y . . .

(This is clearer in the [JS Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/8X5ds/1/))

My CSS so far is:

```
div {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: grey;
  border: 1px solid black; 
}

div:nth-child(odd) {
    background: red;
}

div:nth-child(even) {
    background: blue;
}

div:nth-child(3n) {
    background: yellow;
}
```

But this is nowhere near right.

Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
div:nth-child(odd) {
    background: red;
}
div:nth-child(even) {
    background: blue;
}
div:nth-child(5n+3), div:nth-child(5n+4), div:nth-child(5n) {
    background: yellow;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8X5ds/27/)

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution:

```
div {
  ...
  background: yellow;
}
div:nth-child(10n + 1), div:nth-child(10n + 7) {
  background: red;
}

div:nth-child(10n + 2), div:nth-child(10n + 6) {
  background: blue;
}
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/8X5ds/25/)

Comment: `div { background: yellow }` and remove last block. I see no reason to select `div`s for yellow explicitly.